# como abrir socket para uma rede especifica numa maquina com 2 redes

Tags: c, c++, socket, tcp

Tenho maquina com 2 placas de rede.
Como faço para abrir um socket para uma rede especifica?

Comment: [ajuda](https://www.devmedia.com.br/java-sockets-criando-comunicacoes-em-java/9465)?

Comment: Mas você diz criar um servidor em uma maquina e um cliente em outra?

Comment: Já tenho uma máquina servidor com 1 placa de rede e abro socket para receber conexôes. Também tenho uma máquina client que conversa com esse servidor. Mas agora preciso instalar outra placa de rede neste servidor, sendo a rede 1 para o Geral e a rede 2 para a máquina client. Quero abrir o socket somente para a rede desta minha máquina client.